# Wrong Rest service called with ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

Over the last month I have noticed an odd behavior where the wrong REST service is called with service stack.

Everything seems to be working and then when I add a new REST service, some how my working REST service is not working correctly (i.e. the wrong REST service is called).

I will explain how I have my datacontracts for the services which may explain why I am getting the problem.

I initially had:

```
[DataContract(Name = "MyService", Namespace = "")]
[RestService("/api/v1/dvbs/{ServiceName}", "GET", "application/xml")]
public class GetServiceDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "SessionId", Order = 1)]
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "UserName", Order = 2)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "ServiceName", Order = 3)]
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
}
```

and as I was passing the same data (sessionid, username and servicename) in all my calls, any new service started as:

```
[DataContract(Name = "MyService", Namespace = "")]
[RestService("/api/v1/dvbs/{ServiceName}/tuners", "GET", "application/xml")]
public class GetTunersDto : GetServiceDto
{
}
```

As I mentioned this all worked fine but when I added a new service, when I called "api/v1/dvbs/{ServiceName} the service "api/v2/dvbs/{ServiceName}/tuners" would be called.

I removed the inherited relationship so that I have :

```
[DataContract(Name = "MyService", Namespace = "")]
[RestService("/api/v1/dvbs/{ServiceName}/tuners", "GET", "application/xml")]
public class GetDvbConfigTunersDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "SessionId", Order = 1)]
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "UserName", Order = 2)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "ServiceName", Order = 3)]
    public string ServiceName { get; set;}
}
```

and it works fine now.

What is strange is it was working fine and only when I added a new service at a later date that the wrong mapping incurred.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have 1 Request DTO per service and inheriting Request DTOs inherits the attribute routes which makes it **GetTunersDto** inherit the same routes as **GetServiceDto** which populates ServiceStack with conflicting and ambiguous routes.

The solution is to not use inheritance on DTOs (especially Request DTOs).